# Regex -Check if string start with zero + space or zero alone

Tags: c#, regex

I have this regular expression to math:

- String start with a zero + white space + anything else
- String is a zero

  ```
  "0 fkvjdm" // Must Match
  "0" // Must match
  "0.56" // NOT match
  ```

Here is the regular expression I'm using:

```
^([0]$|([0]\s+.))
```

Is there a way to improve it? or, is it has a bug?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Environment

- VS 2010 .net 4

Comment: What language.  every language has slightly different regex rules.

Comment: `str.StartsWith("0 ")||str.Equals("0")`

Comment: how about zero + white space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- First of all, there is no need to put `0` in a character class.
- Secondly your regex will not match more than a single character after whitespace. As you don't have any quantifier on *dot* - `.` in 2nd part of your regex. To match more characters after whitespace, you should use `.*` (0 or more) or `.+` (1 or more).

To improve in clarity, you can make use of optional quantifier here:

```
^0(\s+.*)?$
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the second character is what causes the match to fail. If the second character is a period, then don't match; otherwise match. `?!` says if what it matches succeeds, fail the whole match. Hence if the second character is a period, it will fail.

```
^0(?!\.).*
```